# Detect the lanscap mode and show an UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developing an iOS application with uses only portrait mode. i would like to show in all the views of my application an image (320*480) when the user turn the iPhone ( lanscape mode)

How i can  do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in the `UIViewController` method `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, which will be called immediately after the user rotates the device.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (self.interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        // add image to self.view
    } else {
        // remove image from self.view
    }
}
```

You could implement this method in each of your app's view controllers.  Alternatively, you could implement this in a custom subclass of `UIViewController` and then have all of your app's view controllers inherit from your custom view controller.

EDIT

As @David Dunham suggests, if all you are trying to do is prevent the app from changing the orientation when the user rotates the device, you can so so easily by implementing the UIViewController method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.  That method should return `YES` for every orientation you want to support, and `NO` for any that you do not wish to support.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // only allow portrait orientation
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: no i don't wont this. an iPhone application witch several views, i would like when the user navigate in the application and whe he turn the iPhone( in lanscape) i would like to show a static image(myImage.png) and when he return  the iPhone (in portrait mode) i will return the to normal view

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to return `NO` from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`?

Comment: i am sorry but i have not understand your question ?

Comment: Did you look up the documentation for that method? I'm wondering if it's the answer to your real question, which is probably "how do I keep the app in portrait mode?"

Comment: no it's not my question. my application have several views ( in portrait mode), i want when the user turn the iphone, all my views will show my image.is it clear for you ?

Comment: No, I didn't realize you were creating an app you wanted rejected. The UI guidelines read, "Avoid displaying a UI element that tells people to rotate the device. Launching in your supported orientation clearly tells people to rotate the device, if required, without adding unnecessary clutter to your UI."

Comment: My app don't tell user to rotate the device. my app does just show a static image when the user rotate the device.